# How can I apply Conditional Formatting on a column if the cell (partially) contains text from a list (another column) in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have one column which contains a list of products sold by suppliers, these are complicated names with many words.
I have another column that contains a list of generic product names (mostly one word).

Now I would like to highlight the cells in the first column if they contain a word from the second column. They do not have to be exact matches, just need to contain one or more of these words.

For example: "Basil 1 packet 50g", should be highlighted as "Basil" is in the other list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following conditional formatting rule.

```
=(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$3:$F$6,B3,1)),1,0))>=1)
```

Refer the below screenshots for sample data.

[image]

[image]

Apply to single cell, B3 in this case and then use Format Painter to apply to all applicable cells.

Comment: That was fast and works like a charm, thank you very much! Do you maybe have any idea how I could match all the words to the corresponding cell? For example that Column C would contain "Basil" at C3 or even "Mango, Orange" if there was a cell containing "Mango Orange Juice" in Column B? Or should I ask this as another question?

Comment: Now that this has worked for you and you have also accepted this as an answer,  I suggest better ask a new question with your sort of new requirements.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again for the speedy reply.

Comment: pretty sure you don't need the ISNUMBER  and then you don't need the IF, just SUM the result. Fewer functions and steps should improve performance, as well as being easier for "future you" to troubleshoot.
(I used COUNT and FIND in my answer then saw you posted while I was typing and we hit on kind of the same idea but using no actual functions in common - the variety of Excel solutions is endless!)

Answer (score 1):

Use FIND to test whether one bit of text is in another. The trick is that FIND will accept a range as input to do exactly what you want and return an array with the number of the first matching character for each item in the range, or a #VALUE error for those which are not found.

You can then convert this array into a "yes/no" by simply counting how many numbers are in it - if they are all errors you get a 0, otherwise a 1.

So this boils down to a simple formula like:

```
=COUNT(FIND($X$1:$X$4,C2))
```

where X1:X4 is the list of generic products and C2 is the cell being checked. You can easily test this formula in a helper column to make sure you are happy you have it configured correctly (such as having $ for the list range so it does not move).

To use this in a conditional format, add a new condition using a formula and enter:

```
=COUNT(FIND($X$1:$X$4,C2))>0
```

making sure that C2 is the first cell in the selected range the format should apply to.

Downside of this, or indeed any method for this sort of problem is that if you have huge lists of data to check against another long list, this is many many text searches at once and performance will suck so you might need to turn off automatic calculation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and the thorough explanation!