# How to extract words from one list that (partially) match another in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Column A contains a list of product names (like "basil 5kg package" and "pineapple frozen 2kg") and column B contains a list of generic names (like "basil" and "pineapple"). I would like to get an array of all of the words from column B that (partially) match the cell in column A.

My first point of action was to highlight a cell if it contains partial text from another column. I found the answer to that problem [at this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997962/conditional-formatting-need-to-highlight-a-cell-if-it-contains-partial-text-fro) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1750867/how-can-i-apply-conditional-formatting-on-a-column-if-the-cell-partially-conta/1750871?noredirect=1#comment2717717_1750871).

Now I need further help with extracting all the matching words that (partially) match. In other words:

- column A contains an entry "Basil Pineapple Juice"
- column B contains entries "Basil" and "Pineapple"
- column C should contain "Basil, Pineapple" after the entry in column A.

| Products | Names | Matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basil Pineapple Juice | Mango | Basil, Pineapple |
| Avocado | Pineapple |  |
| Mango Frozen 2kg | Basil | Mango |
| Mango Orange Juice | Orange | Mango, Orange |

Answer (score 1):

Array formulae for the win:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2))),$B$2:$B$5,""))
```

Note Office 365 is required to use TEXTJOIN. If you don't, the easiest way would be to simply put the answers in separate columns including blanks:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2))),$B$2:$B$5,""))
```

For versions before 365, remember to confirm the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.